# does every simple Jordan closed curve has Inscribed rectangle?

Tags: geometry

is there a simple Jordan closed curve that has 4 points which can not form a rectangle? how about 3 dimension?

Comment: Here's a cool video exploring that problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmgkSdhK4K8

Comment: And here's an article (Theorem 7, pgs 7-8): http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/matschke/SurveyOnSquarePeg_extension14.pdf